# Snakemake Combine analysis of different input types in one workflow

Tags: snakemake

I am sorry for the newbie question regarding snakemake:

Genrally put: 
What is the most elegant way to generate a workflow with two different input types in a combined way.

Let's say I have a number of samples wit different input types. Type a) is raw data in fastq format. Type b) is already assembled.

Now I want a pipeline which does assembly for all samples of type a. Next, it should do annotation  with all samples (a and b).

More exemplaric:
Currently, I have a config file with the entries "samples" (type a) and "genomes" (type b).

I can generate a rule spades for samples and follow-up rule prokka for samples.
I could of course add a second rule prokka2 for genomes but how can I have a combined rule prokka for both types?

Answer (score 0):

Snakemake will figure out by itself that some samples are already partially processed and it will take them forward as required. For example, given these input files:

```
touch s1.fq.gz s2.fq.gz s3.bam s4.bam
```

This workflow will apply rule "assemble" to `s1.fq.gz` and `s2.fq.gz` only and rule `annotate` to all the four:

```
samples= ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sample}.annotated.bam', sample= samples)

rule assemble:
    input:
        fq= '{sample}.fq.gz'
    output:
        bam= '{sample}.bam'
    shell:
        r"""
        my_assembler {input.fq} > {output.bam}
        """

rule annotate:
    input:
        bam= '{sample}.bam'
    output:
        bam= '{sample}.annotated.bam'
    shell:
        r"""
        my_annotator {input.bam} > {output.bam}
        """
```

You can test the execution with `Snakemake -p -n`

Comment: Hey,wonderful! Thank you very much. How would this work with a config.yaml file? See answer below.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. config.yaml appeared just below my initial question.

Comment: Snakemake reads the config file using the `--configfile` options and the content of the file is automatically stored into the variable `config` accessible within the Snakefile. You can use `print(config)` towards the top of the Snakefile to see the structure of `config` (which is basically a dictionary)

Comment: or course. My question is just how I solve the problem when using a config.yaml file? I have an example above

Answer (score 0):

this is how my config.yaml looks like. I just do not know how I can handle files from samples and genomes in one rule (or finde a better config solution)

```
samples:
 SRR653893:
  fw: SRR653893_1.fastq.gz
  rv: SRR653893_2.fastq.gz
 genomes:
   GCF:
    fasta:  GCF_000008985.1_ASM898v1_genomic.fna
```

Answer (score 0):

@user:1114453
The example works fine, apparently because the output files of rule “assemble” for sample 3 and 4 were created beforehand.
I tried to make some structuring for the input data and results. This is my input folder

```
.
`-- input
    |-- s1.fq.gz
    |-- s2.fq.gz
    |-- s3.bam
    `-- s4.bam
```

Using snakemak (example below), I try to make assembly `rule assemble` for `s1` and `s2` and copy the already assembled `rule cp_assemblies` `s3` and `s4` to the assembly folder. Then from the assembly folder I run the annotation of all samples. How I can improve the code to deal with such situation?

```
samples= ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']
assemblies = ['s3', 's4'] 

input_dir="./input/"
results_dir="./results/"

rule all:
    input:
        expand( results_dir + 'annotation/{sample}.annotated.bam', sample= samples)

rule cp_assemblies:
    input:
        fa= input_dir + '{sample}.bam'
    output:
        bam= results_dir + 'assembly/{sample}.bam'
    shell:
        """
        cp -v -f {input.fa} > {output.bam}
        """

rule assemble:
    input:
        fq= input_dir + '{sample}.fq.gz'
    output:
        bam= results_dir + 'assembly/{sample}.bam'
    shell:
        """
        my_assembler {input.fq} > {output.bam}
        """

rule annotate:
    input:
        bam= results_dir + 'assembly/{sample}.bam'
    output:
        bam= results_dir + 'annotation/{sample}.annotated.bam'
    shell:
        """
        my_annotator {input.bam} > {output.bam}
        """
```